# I am getting the below error in the image when I just run a simple Hello World program in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

This is my `build.gradle` file in android studio

[image]

Comment: Begin by putting your code and error log here and not linking us to an external site.

Comment: what is the error??post your log

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugMainDexClassList'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Above comment is the error

Comment: i am new to stack overflow so correct me if i am wrong anywhere

Comment: @KandarpDesai Always put as much [relevant] information as possible. All experts here are willing to help you but, they hate when critical information is missing from the post. To add more information to your post, use the 'edit' button towards the bottom-left corner of your post. A pretty well written page highlighting these points is: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is there any reason you have `multiDexEnabled true` in your `build.gradle`. If not, remove it.

Comment: ya i removed that and tried to run it but still no changes

Answer (score 0):

Clean you project and run again if still error then update you java sdk because you are uses latest studio and latest  gradle version.